# import vector file from illustraror(*.ai files) to aftereffect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-after-effects

[image]I want to import vector file from illustrator to aftereffect but it become pixel ed when it imported . Even when i draw a shape with pen in aftereffect it is not vector . What can i do?

Comment: Check the resolution of your project.

Comment: my resolution is full  , i also turned on continuously rasterize button for my layers , and even when i export the file its pixel ed :(

Comment: can you please provide screenshot of AE with project open?

Comment: i added a screenshot of my work

Comment: After effects is a rastert based software. Same thing happens in photoshop too when you doom in on vector content. Its tsill vectors if you change the size it will remake the pixels of the project.

Comment: so there is no way to have vector shape in aftereffect?

Comment: No you just dont know what your looking at. The comppsitions output is different from what is inside your compisition. Your zooming in on your composition, istead you should scale the contents in the composition. Its like a pixel preview of sorts.

Answer (score 3):

Your composition is 400% zoomed. Switch to 100% and there will be no pixelation. But better make new composition with higher resolution. Current is only 332x554 px.

Comment: I think if you can formulate your asnwer to a bit more netral tone youd get a upvote

Comment: yes thank you i should change it to higher resolution , but in the animation i want to zoom to the eyes of my character that would be a problem then again when it is not vector , any way thank you

Comment: In composition you see actual pixels. When you will animate your character (vector), you can zoom object and it will not become pixelated. But you should change vector object in composition, not zoom composition itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try simple copy and paste elements between Adobe programs. 
When you past a vector element from Ilustrator this element comes like "smart object" and normally you can resize widthout loose resolution.

Comment: can you explain how to copy and paste element , because when i copy my layers in illustrator there is no paste option on AE to past it there!! and do you know why even the shape i draw in AE are not vector? i wonder if AE dose not have ability to show vector shapes :(